# Apply DCT (condition)

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Admittedly, a little stupid question, but I am not sure about the application of dominated convergence theorem for the following:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sqrt{n}\exp(-x^2/n^2)\phi(x) dx$, where $\phi$ is a function in $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. Is it possible to apply DCT? My Question is whether we consider fixed $n$ for the domination condition? then the answer would be yes...?!

Comment: Sort answer is: the dominating function must be independent of $n$. But can you make the question more precise? To what functions do you want to apply DCT?

Comment: I want to write: $...= \int_{\mathbb{R}}  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n}\exp(-x^2/n^2)\phi(x) dx$

Comment: Then what is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt n e^{-x^2/n^2}$? Also, what happens if you drop the $\sqrt n$ factor?

Comment: your first limit is $\infty$ If I drop it, it is bounded obviously by $1$ and I can apply it

Comment: But the question is nevertheless, is it an application of DCT in the first case or not...

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot apply the DCT. The dominating function must be independent of $n$, and this does not happen here. If the support of $\phi$ is contained in an interval $[-R,R]$, then
$$
\sqrt n\,e^{-x^2/n^2}\ge\sqrt n\,e^{-R^2/n^2}\ge\sqrt n,\quad |x|\le R.
$$
You should know from previous questions that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp(x^2/n^2)\phi(x)\,dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)\,dx.
$$
If $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)\,dx\ne0$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sqrt{n}\exp(-x^2/n^2)\phi(x)\,dx=\pm\infty,
$$
depending on the sign of $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)\,dx$.